# Pyspark DataFrame Grouping by item that doesn't belong to the group

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark and am stuck in a situation could you please help me in obtaining a result in a manner as:

| customer_id | item_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tx1 | 15 |
| 1 | tx2 | 10 |
| 1 | tx3 | 14 |
| 2 | tx1 | 15 |
| 2 | tx4 | 12 |
| 3 | tx2 | 10 |
| 2 | tx6 | 43 |
| 4 | tx4 | 12 |
| 5 | tx8 | 76 |
| 6 | tx6 | 43 |
| 5 | tx6 | 43 |
| 3 | tx6 | 43 |

And want to know for each `item`:

- The count of `customers` that didn't purchase this `item`
- The sum of the `amount` of `items` that are not the `customers` of this `item`.

So the final table would look like:

| item_id | target_cust | taget_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tx1 | 4 | 227 |
| tx2 | 4 | 201 |
| tx3 | 5 | 297 |
| tx4 | 4 | -- |
| tx6 | 3 | -- |
| tx8 | 5 | -- |

please help me in getting a similar output, any suggestions in the direction would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First group by `customer_id` and get list of purchased `item_id` with the associated `amount` like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

items_by_customer_df = df.groupBy("customer_id").agg(
    F.collect_set("item_id").alias("items"),
    F.sum("amount").alias("target_amount")

)

items_by_customer_df.show()
#+-----------+---------------+-------------+
#|customer_id|items          |target_amount|
#+-----------+---------------+-------------+
#|1          |[tx1, tx2, tx3]|39           |
#|2          |[tx1, tx6, tx4]|70           |
#|3          |[tx2, tx6]     |53           |
#|5          |[tx6, tx8]     |119          |
#|4          |[tx4]          |12           |
#|6          |[tx6]          |43           |
#+-----------+---------------+-------------+
```

Now, join this grouped dataframe with distinct `item_id`s from original `df` using negation of `array_contains` as condition, then group by `item_id` and do aggregations `count(customer_id)` +  `sum(amount)`:

```
result = df.select("item_id").distinct().join(
    items_by_customer_df,
    ~F.array_contains("items", F.col("item_id"))
).groupBy("item_id").agg(
    F.count("customer_id").alias("target_cust"),
    F.sum("target_amount").alias("target_amount")
)

result.show()
#+-------+-----------+-------------+
#|item_id|target_cust|target_amount|
#+-------+-----------+-------------+
#|    tx2|          4|          244|
#|    tx4|          4|          254|
#|    tx1|          4|          227|
#|    tx8|          5|          217|
#|    tx3|          5|          297|
#|    tx6|          2|           51|
#+-------+-----------+-------------+
```